# How could I know I need to approach with a logarithm among time complexities in this example?

Tags: time-complexity

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5Nis.png)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjDY5RbILno

I watched a video to understand the concept of time complexity.

But I still wonder how I could I I need to approach with a logarithm among time complexities.

I know this video is for explaining O(log n), but if I see this with not knowing any result of time complexity. How can I get the clue?

Thanks in advance.

I have been watching some youtubes